# How to find indegree of a vertex in ArangoDB?

Tags: arangodb

I am trying to find all the dangling documents in my vertex collection. For that I suppose i will have to find all the vertices with indegree=0. How can I do this using AQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a document with `_key` = `A` in a collection `Verts` and an edge collection `Edges`, then you can determine the indegree like this:

```
RETURN LENGTH(FOR v IN INBOUND 'Verts/A' Edges RETURN true)
```

If you have a named graph `MyGraph` then use this:

```
RETURN LENGTH(FOR v IN INBOUND 'Verts/A' GRAPH 'MyGraph' RETURN true)
```

To determine which vertices have no inbound edges you could do:

```
FOR s IN Verts
  FILTER NOT FIRST(FOR v IN INBOUND s._id Edges LIMIT 1 RETURN true)
  RETURN s._id
```

To find dangling vertices (no connected edges whatsoever), you would have to change `INBOUND` to `ANY` however.

Instead of a subquery traversal it might be better to utilize the edge indexes without traversal:

```
FOR v IN Verts
  FILTER NOT FIRST(FOR e IN Edges
    FILTER v._id == e._from || v._id == e._to
    LIMIT 1
    RETURN true)
  RETURN v._id
```

A traversal using a named graph has the benefit that all edge collections of the graph are considered. If it has multiple vertex collections, then you do need to check each collection individually still.